# Querying DBLP database

Tags: c#, .net, rdf, dotnetrdf

I want to query the DBLP database using this end point:

```
http://dblp.l3s.de/d2r/snorql/
```

My code snippet:

```
String st = "";
String qry = "";
String uri_V;
String dguri_V;

uri_V = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
dguri_V = "http://dbpedia.org";


// Modify if need......
//String ns = "\""+TextBox1.Text.ToString()+"\"";
// String qry = "SELECT DISTINCT ?name WHERE { ?person foaf:name ?name.FILTER regex(str(?name),"+ns+").}";
if (radiosrch.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    qry = "SELECT ?title WHERE {?game <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:First-person_shooters> .?game foaf:name ?title .}ORDER by ?title";
}
else// if (radiosrch.SelectedIndex == 1) 
{
    // qry= "query for publisher."
    qry = "SELECT DISTINCT ?Concept WHERE {[] a ?Concept} LIMIT 10";
}

//Common
SparqlRemoteEndpoint endpoint = new SparqlRemoteEndpoint(new Uri(uri_V), dguri_V);
SparqlResultSet results = endpoint.QueryWithResultSet(qry);
foreach (SparqlResult result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    st = st + result.ToString() + "\n";
}
TextBox3.Text = st.ToString();
```

It's working for dbpedia but I can't find the `uri_v`, `dguri_v` to query DBLP database with an endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever come across a SNORQL UI for an endpoint you can always find the actual SPARQL endpoint URI from the Page Title and Header, for your example note it says the following in both places:

> Snorql: Exploring http://dblp.l3s.de/d2r/sparql

The URI here is the one you want for your `uri_v` variable.

Often the default graph (your `dguri_v`) argument is not required at all, it just happens to be required for DBPedia.  With just the SPARQL endpoint URI you should now be able to query your desired endpoint, make sure to use the constructor for `SparqlRemoteEndpoint` that only takes the endpoint URI as the argument.

### Edit

SNORQL is a UI and as such it is **not** a SPARQL endpoint, it is merely a HTML+JS wrapper over an endpoint.

As described above the UI will show the URI of the *actual SPARQL endpoint* that it is querying.  This is the URI you need if you want to write code that queries the *endpoint* (regardless of the toolkit/API you are using).

Comment: @user2242304 Clarified my answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800269/net-rdf-dblp-dataset-querying
plz help me resolve this,it contains the error!!

Comment: thanx a lot RobV sir,i m still struggling with my problem but ur explanation has given me a new ray of hope,i shall continue working on it,maybe the problem is with server only coz it works perfectly for dbpedia,should i load the rdf dump instead and query it??